# Constant error: "A setting has changed that requires a restart to take effect"

Tags: visual-studio-code

*"press the restart button to restart Visiual Studio Code and enable the setting."*

Now Im going to preface this by saying that this is quite possibly the most annoying thing I have ever experienced in my years computing.

I'm new to VS Code and as such I am knee deep in my settings.json a lot of the time. Especially moreso when Ive just installed a new extension and it comes with loads of parameters, alnd all sorts of goodies - sort of like I did today when I got home from work.

I open settings.json. I add a comment line indicating a new section for my new extension's myriad of settings I half understand, and move any auto-generated config settings from the bottom to the freshly minted position. I start typing, the widget pops up letting me know about all 70+ settings I can fiddle with as much as I please.

I hit tab on the first entry, it goes down. Tab again, "true" goes down.

> ***"A setting has changed that requires a restart to take effect"***

OKAY no problem VS code. Quick restart, back to my config.

I start typing the extension again, I get 200ms in or however long it takes for that widgit to appear, and

> ***"A setting has changed that requires a restart to take effect"***

I watch the text in my editor contort as the settings are unloaded and reloaded and unloaded again.

I got the first 4 characters of the extension name typed out before this lovely notification reappears.

---

Now,

when this happens a few times its a little irritating.

BUT THIS IS ***CONSTANT*** .**Every. Single. Line.** I try to add. Each and every setting. Sometimes 2 or 3 times before I actually get the string down, never-mind its value.

I don't know what to do, I am legitimately going to rip my hair out. This is by far easily up there with one of the most frustrating things I have ever been forced to endure. It is *relentless.*

I dont know what else to do. Ive tried all I can think of.

I just want to learn and use my new extension.

Please for the love of anything help me.

Please.

Comment: Yes. Help me please. Something with Python language server. I have only few hairs left to pull out. I don't want to be bold. HELP PLEASE!